# How would I find the series generated by $e^x$ + $4x^2$? (exponential generating function)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function, generating-functions

Can I simply say: $e^x$ generates 1 + x/1! + $x^2$/2! + ....
and add on the $4x^2$ term? so the sequence generated instead of being 1,1,1,1,1,... is 1,1,4,1,1,1...?

Comment: Yes, but remember to multiply the extra term by the factorial!

Comment: @Chappers, sorry do I not just add it to the respective term in the case to the x^2 coefficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall, an exponential generating function has the representation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> The expression $4x^2$ can be written as $$8\frac{x^2}{2!}$$ to fit the representation in (1). The sequence of coefficients of the exponential generating function $e^x+4x^2$ is therefore
>   \begin{align*}
> 1,1,\color{blue}{9},1,1,1,\ldots
> \end{align*}